# MediaPlayer.setDataSource() and prepare() not working - android

Tags: android, media-player, prepare

I'm having a crack at using the MediaPlayer object and not having much success.  If I add a sound asset to my raw folder and call it using the int value within R, it works fine.  But I want to be able to pull things off of url.

According to all of the documentation I've read setDataSource() should accept a string param with a url to a file.

I keep getting an IO exception on the prepare() statement.  I've even tried copying the file locally and still no dice.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {
        mp.setDataSource("http://www.urltofile.com/file.mp3");
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try MediaPlayer.create(), you also may want to start only after player is actually ready, for example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://www.urltofile.com/file.mp3"));
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Works great with external URLs (eg, "http://google.com/") but throws an exception when trying local assets (eg, "file://android_asset/sound.mp3") :(

Comment: @richtaur what makes you to use android assets instead of regular resources? MediaPlaye.create(Context context, int resid) should work great for app internal media files.

Comment: Would just make my stuff more organized :) Resources folder is good enough.

Answer (score 14):

For streams, you should call `prepareAsync()`, which returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered.