# Null Pointer in OnListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

So I am using this code to access the data of song that I want to play but I am getting null pointer exception whenever I am using media player.I used toast to check whether the filename i.e. path of file is correct or not but its coming out to be just fine.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //  l.setClickable(false);
         music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                            musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                            String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

                      try {
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

I am getting error on this line

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
```

Logcat:-

```
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at prac.tise_music.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:136)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:342)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3569)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1831)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
06-17 17:31:36.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5059):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: so check which one is null, mMediaPlayer or filename...

Comment: check if (filename != null) then proceed.

Comment: Obviously you are getting null in filename check it (filename != null)

Comment: I have tried null command but I am still getting same error.

Comment: it seems that You don´t have initialized Your mMediaPlayer....

Comment: My media player is comin out to be null everytime,any idea on how to sort his problem?
Check my edit for recent changes but everytime my media player is coming out to be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar kind of problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625680/mediaplayer-setdatasource-better-to-use-path-or-filedescriptor).

May be it serve your purpose.

One more suggestion,Try `MediaPlayer.create()`, you also may want to start only after player is actually ready, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533837/mediaplayer-setdatasource-and-prepare-not-working-android):

Comment: Hey its sorted out.Problem was in initialization of media player.

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading file from external storage then first give "read external storage permission" in your manifiest. because you are not able to read file.

Comment: There is no problem in reading file as problem is only coming when I am using Media Player.Otherwise I am using toast to print file path and its coming out correct.

Comment: long id = /* retrieve it from somewhere */;
Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), contentUri);

// ...prepare and start...