# File not Found Exception occurs when accessing flutter assets

Tags: java, dart, flutter, filenotfoundexception

i am trying to write a plugin to play audio files that are stored in assets folder of flutter package and have done like this

```
if(call.method.equals("playMusic"))
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onMethodCall: play music function called");

    String fileLocation = call.argument("file");
    Log.d(TAG, "onMethodCall: file requested is "+fileLocation);
    AssetManager assetManager = registrar.context().getAssets();
    String key = registrar.lookupKeyForAsset(fileLocation);
    Log.d(TAG, "onMethodCall: key is "+key);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMethodCall: found assets " + Arrays.toString(assetManager.list("assets/")));
        fd= assetManager.openFd(key);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(),fd.getStartOffset(),fd.getLength());
        fd.close();
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        result.success("played successfully");
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "onMethodCall: exception occured "+e.toString());
    result.success("playing failed");
  }
}
```

fileLocation is correctly passed as

> assets/river.m4a

i have checked and found out that the key which is looked up by registrar is

> flutter_assets/assets/river.m4a

and the file is present in package at

> assets/flutter_assets/assets/river.m4a

but still when i run the application it throws

> D/TunePlugin: onMethodCall: exception occured java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/assets/river.m4a

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533837/mediaplayer-setdatasource-and-prepare-not-working-android (Android native q/a though). What code line  causes the exception?

Comment: acception occurs at   **fd= assetManager.openFd(key);**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It came to me as a surprise that when i ran the same app through terminal i.e. Git bash 
it yielded me no problems and the song played without any errors. When i am running the same app through android studio it is yielding FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 6):

Inside your pubspec.yaml file add this...

```
flutter:
    assets:
-assets/flutter_assets/assets/river.m4a
```

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you try to access compressed files.

You can add the following directive to your `build.gradle` located at `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'm4a'
}
```